# Pandas: How to convert a one-hot-encoded dataframe to an adjacency matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame *df*, of the form:

```
      Col1   Col2    Col3   
0      0       1       0
1      1       1       0
2      0       1       1
3      1       1       0
```

I need a *new df* of the form:

```
        Col1    Col2    Col3
Col1      0       2       0    
Col2      2       0       1
Col3      0       1       0
```

Basically the values represent the co-occurrences of two given columns for all rows.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Why is `Col2/Col1` equal to 2?

Comment: Sorry, I had missed a row. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply leverage [`matrix-multiplication`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) there -

```
In [21]: df_out = df.T.dot(df)

In [22]: np.fill_diagonal(df_out.values, 0)

In [23]: df_out
Out[23]: 
      Col1  Col2  Col3
Col1     0     2     0
Col2     2     0     1
Col3     0     1     0
```

Comment: Beat me to it !

Comment: Great, I try to using dot, but forget the T :-)

Comment: @Wen Yeah I have seen you use that and was surprised to not see this time around from you.

Comment: What I have try to do is `df.dot(df.columns.values)`, but this is really hard to split . :-)